# Create form with n tags as fields representing the values

Tags: reactjs, forms, antd

I want to create a [tag](https://ant.design/components/tag/) list which represents a string array given by an api.

```
import { Tag } from 'antd'

const TagList = () => {
   const items = ['Tag1', 'Tag2', 'Tag3'];

   return (
      <>
        {
           items.map((item) => (
              <Tag>{item}</Tag>
           )
        }
      </>
   )
}
```

How can I wrap this in a [Form.List](https://ant.design/components/form/#Form.List) so that in the end I can send the data array back to an api endpoint? With let's say reordered items e.G. `['Tag3', 'Tag1', 'Tag2']`

My first approach was like

```
<Form.List name={props.tagListName} initialValue={items}>
   {(fields, { add, remove, move }) => {
      return (
         <div>
            {fields.map((field) => (
               <>
                  <Form.Item {...field}>                  
                     <CustomTagComponent
                        name={id}
                        closable={items.length > 1}
                        isDrag={activeId === id}
                        handleClose={onClose}
                     />
                  </Form.Item>
               </>
            ))}
         </div>
      )
   }}
</Form.List>
```

I tried to add items as initialValue to the List, but that didn't work out.

How can I create `items.length` tags, combined with a Form containing these values?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I found a solution:

Created a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-dawn-tbuqjl?file=/src/App.js) for it.

Comments, opinions or better solutions appreciated :)